# Calling code-behind from button - No overload for matches

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a FormView used to edit records but when the user presses the Button, it also needs to do some back-end stuff in the code-behind. For this I need to pass the ID of the record.

Currently this is my code in the page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="savebtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"   
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Save Changes" 
                    OnClick="setProcessProgress"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'  />
```

And this is a stripped-down version of my code-behind:

```
protected void setProcessProgress(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.CommandName == "Update")
              ID_p =   Int32.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
        }
```

I'm getting the `No overload for 'setProcessProgress' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

I tried changing the EventArgs to CommandEventArgs and it didn't work either.
If I use `OnCommand` instead of `OnClick` it just doesn't call `setProcessProgress`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN Documentation on [`FormViewCommandEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewcommandeventargs.aspx).

> The ItemCommand event is raised when a button within the FormView
>   control is clicked. This allows you to provide an event-handling
>   method that performs a custom routine whenever this event occurs.
>
> Buttons within a FormView control can also invoke some of the built-in
>   functionality of the control. To perform one of these operations, set
>   the CommandName property of a button to one of the values in the
>   following table.

The event is not assigned to the Button's OnClick event, it is actually assigned to the `FormViews` [`ItemCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcommand.aspx) Event

i.e

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="setProcessProgress">


<asp:LinkButton ID="savebtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"    
                CommandName="Update" Text="Save Changes"  
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `EventArgs e` in your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void setProcessProgress(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
       if (btn.CommandName=="Update")
       {
           ...
           Response.Write("Updated");
           ...
       }
   }
```